# Use cygnus or QuantumLeap for context historization?

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

in our current fiware setup (only Orion) we would like to store the history of contexts. I know QuantumLeap and Cygnus and unsure know which one is designed for that.

My current understanding:

- [QuantumLeap](https://quantumleap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/): store time-series data which can be queried by time - and optional some more data
- [Cygnus](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/short-term-history/index.html): write history of specific contexts (i.e. a parking spot) and fetch the history of that parking spot

Could someone help me there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are valid.

Cygnus persists the information into several databases (for NGSIv2 e.g.m HDFS, MySQL, MongoDB, DynamoDB, PostgreSQL, or Elasticsearch among others; for NGSI-LD e.g., PostgreSQL and PostGIS).

QuantumLeap persists the historical information into CartoDB using NGSIv2. NGSI-LD is currently experimental choice.

Therefore, the selection is usually conditional on which database and which version of the NGSI API you want to use in your concrete case.